# How to avoid errors when passing arguments to class with kwargs?

Tags: python, class, keyword-argument

I have a class with an init function like this:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for arg in kwargs:
            self.__dict__[arg] = kwargs[arg]
```

It goes correct when I pass in a dictionary:

```
colors = {“i”:”blue”, “j”:”green”}
newClass = myClass(**colors)

print(newClass.i)
>>blue
```

But I can’t seem to “break” it and I’m afraid that it won’t be doing error handling correctly.

```
colors = {“i”:”blue”, “j”:”green”}
name = “John”
newClass = myClass(**colors, name=name)

print(newClass.name)
>>John
```

Is there something wrong here that I’m missing? Why will it take a named argument AFTER an unnamed one?

Comment: You need to fix your quotes - use `"` instead. Otherwise your code will break with a SyntaxError.

Answer (score 0):

What you've shown isn't an error. `name=name` is a keyword argument, and is included in `kwargs`, just like the contents of `**colors`. Now, if you had done something like

```
>>> foo = ""
>>> newclass = MyClass(**colors, foo, name=name)
```

You'd get an error:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    newclass = MyClass(**colors, foo, name=name)
                                               ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument unpacking
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're talking about the line:

```
newClass = myClass(**colors, name=name)
```

You say that this function is "taking a named argument AFTER an unnamed one".  That's not what's going on.  All of the parameters passed to your class's constructor are named parameters.

In this context, `**colors` expands to pairs of named arguments, so in the case of your example, the line of code above is equivalent to:

```
newClass = myClass(i="blue", j="green", name=name)
```

See: https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/dict_unpack.html